# How do I save an Ultrahand creation to Autobuild without changing it?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I am currently working on building a hoverbike that I can save with Autobuild. Since I've got it aligned and it flies straight, I'd rather not change it. However, I attached a stake to one of the parts to hold it in place, and the stake shows up in the completed hoverbike.

Even though I can detach the stake, it remains in the version of the hoverbike that is correctly balanced. The problem I'm facing is that the Autobuild process seems to necessitate some form of modification to the build for the latest state to qualify as an Autobuild entry, and I'd like to avoid this. I'm looking for a way to save my existing build as a favorite without altering it. Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: You mean you want to add that build in your history? Can't you just fuse a random item (an apple) or a small battery?

Comment: Try attaching a dragon part. In addition to counting as the "change" required to show up in the autobuild history, this will also increase the distance you can go from the vehicle before it despawns.

Comment: I had a similar problem. When building my bike, I attached a wooden box as a support. Apparently, hoverbikes don't work very well with giant boxes attached.

Comment: Can you not just add this final build to your autobuild favorites, and have it at the top of your autobuild options? I'm trying to figure out the purpose of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @king14nyr maybe it's not something OP built, but a Yiga build left somewhere

Comment: @pinckerman Ah, fair point!

Comment: The issue is that i built the machine on a stake to make sure everything is aligned and when w was done i unattached the stake but the last entry in the autobuild is the hoverbike still with the stake in it. there is no way for my last entry to be just the hokerbike.

Comment: Even fusing a battery on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you add something small but useful like a headlight, battery, or dragon part, it will show up in the history. Also, if you just built this recently, it should still be in the history, allowing you to favorite it. However, there is no way to add it to your history other than attaching another material. A dragon part, even when autobuilt, is a potent attachment that might save as much zonaite as it costs.

Comment: It doesn't have to be "useful". I usually fuse random common items I have, like apples.

Comment: Yes, but this means you have to either take out an extra item or spend 3 extra zonaite each time.

Comment: That's why I use an apple, I always have them

Comment: That sucks, im hesitant to add anything since i finally got a hoverbike to fly in a perfect straight line and i'm afraid that adding anything to it would mis-align it. if i need to go that route, ide rather just use the last entry in the autobuild history and un-attach the stake every time i build it.

Comment: You can attach an apple and then unattach it, both the appled and unappled versions should then be at the top of your history

Comment: @Pyritie unfortunately unattaching the apple doesn't add a new entry to the autobuild history so i'm back where i started.